# How to terminate a QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

`QThread::terminate()` documentation states that it is discouraged to terminate a thread by calling this function.
In my program, I need to terminate a thread before it finishes execution. The thread is performing some heavy computation and I want the user to have control to stop calculation.
How can I do that instead of calling `QThread::terminate()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set a flag from outside the thread that is checked by the computation within the thread and stop the calculation if the flag is set.

Answer (score 1):

Using flags is an obvious and the most common way to do the trick, but if you are working on a linux/unix platform I would advise you to use pipes instead. I had the same issue where I used a flag (this makes the code threadunsafe, and bugs arising out of such a flag are hard to trace), then I changed the implementation to use pipes which were an efficient way to do the needful.

If you want, for a linux platform I can show you how to use pipes to terminate a QThread.

You may also have windows equivalent of pipes, which I don't know much about as I haven't done much of programming on Windows platform.

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm in Windows platform and I have no knowledge about pipes.

Comment: @Donotalo,

Pipes are a form of Interprocess communication (IPC), as the names suggests, it is used to communicate between threads. I used pipes to eliminate certain synchronisation issues that cropped up with the use of singleton pattern(or antipattern I should say :-) ).

Comment: The problem iith a flag occurs simply because it's a shared datastructure, and must be sufficiently protected (e.g. by a `QMutex`). A slightly dirty way is to abuse `QThread::setPriority(QThread::IdlePriority);` and check `QThread::priority` in your calculation loop.

Answer (score 1):

Best is to use flag + mutex which will make the solution thread safe.